# Three.js - How to update line connecting objects during render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three.js canvas with circles that move independently. Initially These circles are connected via a single line that holds the same geometry as all of their positions.

I'm having trouble updating the line's own geometry as these circles move.

I'm searching through all the scene's children to find any child named 'item' and updating the x & y position. When I try to update the geometry of the line it either disappears or stays static (as per code below).

**How can I successfully update the line geometry on every frame to match the moving circles?**

```
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;

var numItems = 40;
var xspeed  // Speed of the shape
var yspeed  // Speed of the shape
var lineGeometry;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  container = document.createElement( 'div' );
  document.body.appendChild( container );
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff3000);
  var geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry( 15, 20 );
  lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  for ( var i = 0; i < numItems; i ++ ) {
    var item = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0x000000 } ) );
    item.position.x = (-180)+(i*Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1);
    item.position.y = (-50)+(i*Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1);
    item.xspeed = Math.random() * (2 - 1);
    item.yspeed = Math.random() * ( 1-0.5);
    item.name="item";
    scene.add( item );
    lineGeometry.vertices.push( item.position );
  }

var line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } ) );
line.name="line";
scene.add( line );

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
}

function render() {
  for(var i=0; i < scene.children.length; i++){
    var newPosition;
    if(scene.children[i].name === 'item'){
      scene.children[i].position.x = scene.children[i].position.x + scene.children[i].xspeed;
      scene.children[i].position.y = scene.children[i].position.y + scene.children[i].yspeed;

      newPosition = scene.children[i].position;

      if(scene.children[i].position.x > window.innerWidth/2 || scene.children[i].position.x < -window.innerWidth/2)
      {
        scene.children[i].xspeed = scene.children[i].xspeed * (-1);
      }
      if(scene.children[i].position.y > window.innerWidth/2 || scene.children[i].position.y < -window.innerWidth/2)
      {
        scene.children[i].yspeed = scene.children[i].yspeed * (-1);
      }
    }

    if(scene.children[i].name === 'line'){
      scene.children[i].vertices = newPosition;
    }
  }



  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.z = 1000;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your points of the line geometry are already referenced to positions of circles, so there's no need to assign new values for them on every rendering of the scene.

If you make the `line` as a global variable and also add another global variable to store the circles in an array, then you can simplify the things.

```
var camera, scene, renderer, line, circles = [];
```

and then you can just push your `item` into the array:

```
circles.push(item);
scene.add(item);
```

thus your render function will become like this:

```
function render() {
  circles.forEach(circle => {
    circle.position.x += circle.xspeed;
    circle.position.y += circle.yspeed;

    if (circle.position.x > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.x < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
      circle.xspeed *= -1;
    }
    if (circle.position.y > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.y < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
      circle.yspeed *= -1;
    }
  });
  line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```js
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, line, circles = [];

var numItems = 40;
var xspeed // Speed of the shape
var yspeed // Speed of the shape
var lineGeometry;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xff3000);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(15, 20);
  lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var item = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: Math.random() * 0x000000
    }));
    item.position.x = (-180) + (i * Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1);
    item.position.y = (-50) + (i * Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1);
    item.xspeed = Math.random() * (2 - 1);
    item.yspeed = Math.random() * (1 - 0.5);
    circles.push(item);
    scene.add(item);
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(item.position);
  }

  line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
  }));
  line.name = "line";
  scene.add(line);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  circles.forEach(circle => {
    circle.position.x += circle.xspeed;
    circle.position.y += circle.yspeed;

    if (circle.position.x > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.x < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
      circle.xspeed *= -1;
    }
    if (circle.position.y > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.y < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
      circle.yspeed *= -1;
    }
  });
  line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  // this is the most important thing to set this flag to true,
  //when you change coordinates of vertices of a geometry

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```